# Class attribute not showing up as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I don't understand why the following code is returning an error `AttributeError: 'Dice' object has no attribute 'die1'` in the `__str__` method. I know that I have created one, and my debugger shows it as a class attribute. What is wrong with this (simple) code?

```
   class Dice(QMainWindow) :
        """A game of Dice."""

        def __init__(self, parent = None):
            """Build a game with two dice."""

            QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

            super(Dice, self).__init__(parent)
            uic.loadUi("Dice.ui", self)

            self.die1 = Die()
            self.die2 = Die()
            self.rollButton.clicked.connect(self.rollButtonClickedHandler)


        def __str__( self ):
            """String representation for Dice.
            """
            return "Die1: %s\nDie2: %s" % ( str(self.die1),  str(self.die2) )
```

Comment: What's obviously wrong is that you `__init__` the base class twice (once explicitly and once with `super` -- lose one of them!), but that doesn't explain the error you observe.

Comment: The error is raised because `loadUi` calls `__str__` on your class instance (which you passed to it as `self`) before `die1` has been set.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the double contructor call, I noticed that one myself, after a night's sleep! However ekhumoro nailed the problem! Thanks! Care to comment further? I'm switching from PyQt4 to PyQt5 and have always compiled the ui outside of my code. I thought I would need to load the ui before setting up signals, Is that true? Also why would loadUi call the str method on my class?

Comment: if you are on python 3x you can call parent methods without the class. ''super().__init__(parent)''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the error is raised because `loadUi` calls `__str__` on the class instance (i.e. `self`) before `die1` has been set.

The reason *why* the `uic` module does this is because it collects a lot of debugging information whilst parsing the `ui` file, and that includes logging the object passed as the `baseinstance` argument of `loadUi`.

Unfortunately, it does this by (indirectly) calling `__str__` when it probably should be calling `__repr__`. (Or possibly just not logging debugging information *at all* when calling the python API functions. The command-line interface has an option for *switching on* debugging, but it seems this only controls whether the logged information is displayed, rather than whether it is gathered in the first place).

It certainly is natural to want to call `loadUi` at the earliest possible point during initialisation - just as you'd do with `setupUi`. But no matter how you load the ui into your application, `uic` will generate the code in exactly the same way. The only difference with `loadUi` is that it calls [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) on the generated code at runtime, whereas with `pyuic`, the same code is just imported as a static module.

There a number of ways to solve your immediate problem. Personally, I think I would probably choose to pre-initialise `die1/die2` as class attributes:

```
   class Dice(QMainWindow) :
        """A game of Dice."""
        die1 = die2 = None

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            """Build a game with two dice."""
            super().__init__(parent)
            uic.loadUi("Dice.ui", self)
            self.die1 = Die()
            self.die2 = Die()
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual answer: move the `uic.loadUi` call to *after* you create the `die`s.

Comments on code:

- Only call the constructor once (not once as `QMainWindow` and once as `super`)
- When using `%s`, you don't need to also call `str()` -- that's what `%s` does.
- If writing Python3 only code, your `super` call can leave out the `Dice, self` portion and just be `super().__init__(parent)`